# Add windows forms objects to drawing

Tags: c#, .net-4.7.1

I have a class with windows forms objects:

```
class SpecialButton {
Button button;
Label label1;
Label label2;
Label label3;
}
```

How can I make it drawable? And How can I make instance of this class drawn in Form?

Comment: What do you mean with "drawable"?. These are Control objects and they start to exists, at least, only after you have instantiated them (new Button() etc), set their position (Location property) and added to the Controls collection of a container object (IE Form, GroupBox, Panel etc)

Comment: That's a UserControl.  Not the best way to do this, instead make Button the base class and use TextRenderer.DrawText() to draw the strings in OnPaint().

Comment: @HansPassant I will try that out! Thanks!